# MySQL - is it possible to use a column as a tablename?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Suppose that we have, in **mysql**, a table "mytable"

with the columns: `id, title, type`.

Is it possible to use its column as a table name in the same query?

For example:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title FROM mytable m INNER JOIN m.type WHERE m.id=2
```

Where "type" will give me the name of the table to do the inner join.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As far as I understand, each row in `myTable` will have a field called `type` which will contain the name of another table.  He then wants to join each row to the table specified in that field.  (Each row to a different table, the target table being specified by a string in that row)

Comment: **YES**, only in stored procedure or user defined function

Comment: @ajreal - Care to offer some sample code?

Comment: @Dems lmgtfy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593078/mysql-stored-functions-dynamic-variable-table-column-names

Comment: @ajreal - So it's still as per my answer, loop through the rows and build dynamic sql for each row?

Comment: @Dems Close, defined once and can be used subsequently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Sorry :(

The closest you can get (afaik) is to cursor through your main table and write dynamic html for the join for each row.  VERY slow.

Or, find a new design pattern - Is there scope for you to post a question about what you are trying to achieve and how people may go about that?

Comment: Dynamic HTML? I think you meant SQL? ;)

Comment: ROTFL!  I think I'll leave that mistake in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all of your type data in a single table ? and then partition the table by type.