# Set a variable to identify a particular field to sum in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 'FY14' AS YEAR, 
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'KAE',sc.bal03,0)) AS NIBD,
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'GAA',sc.bal03,0)) AS Labor
FROM summarycurrent AS sc
```

`sc.bal03` is field for values for the month of Dec. Values for the month of Jan are stored in `sc.bal04`. I have queries that reference `sc.bal03` as many as 20 times and changing the field name to pull data from a different month is repetitive and prone to mistakes. I would like to use a variable to tell the query which field to sum from, but i can't figure out if it's even possible.

My current (non functioning) query looks like this:

```
SET @Var:= sc.Bal03;
SELECT 'FY14' AS YEAR, 
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'KAE',@Var,0)) AS NIBD,
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'GAA',@Var,0)) AS Labor
FROM summarycurrent AS sc
```

I get either `FY14, 0, 0` as the result, or an error that `sc.` is not in the field list.
I just want to define `sc.Bal03` as the field to sum once, instead of doing so multiple times.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593078/mysql-stored-functions-dynamic-variable-table-column-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use subquery and rename `bal03` or `bal04` as `value` like this

```
SELECT 'FY14' AS YEAR,
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'KAE',value,0)) AS NIBD,
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'GAA',value,0)) AS Labor
FROM 
 (SELECT acctcode, bal03 as value FROM 
 summarycurrent
  )as sc
```

or

```
SELECT 'FY14' AS YEAR,
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'KAE',value,0)) AS NIBD,
 SUM(IF(acctcode = 'GAA',value,0)) AS Labor
FROM 
 (SELECT acctcode, bal04 as value FROM 
 summarycurrent
  )as sc
```

This way you only need to change `bal03` or `bal04` once.

Comment: I am sure this answer will work. The only draw backs are that in some similar queries I already have sub-queries that may then require multiple levels of subs, and the reference is further down the query not so readily 'in my face' to edit. Failing another solution I'll mark this as answered.